Probabilistic Method to construct a low intersecting family of sets
I have a question to the following exercise I found in this book:

If I understand the hint correctly, we construct some set $S_i$ by going through each element of the "universe" $\{1, ..., d\}$ and adding it to $S_i$ with probabillty $\ell/d$ (thus we have $E[|S_i|] = \ell$).
So, given two sets $S_i$ and $S_j$ with $i \not = j$, we have that some  $x \in (S_i \cap S_j)$ with probabillity $p := (\ell/d)^2$. And thus,
$$Pr(|S_i \cap S_j| \geq a) = \sum_{i = a}^\ell \binom{d}{i} p^i (1-p)^{d-i}$$
How I understand the prob. method, if we can show that $m \cdot \sum_{i = a}^\ell \binom{d}{i} p^i (1-p)^{d-i} < 1$, we are done. However, I have no clue how to proceed from here to reach the statement of the task...

There's a few flaws with your method, the first one being is that each $S_i$ is not guaranteed to have the correct number of elements. If you'd like it to be close to the expected value, then you can get around that problem by Chernoff's; but since you want the exact number of elements there's no getting around that problem. So instead, let's choose $S_i$ uniformly at random among all $\ell$-sets of $[d]$, that way, we get condition one for free. Suppose we've chosen $S_1,\cdots, S_{i-1}$ such that they form an $(\ell,a)$-design for some $i\leq m$ (notice that  trivially, the family $\{S_1\}$ is an $(\ell,a)$-design); we'll show that we can find $S_i$. Now, when we choose $S_i$ we get
\begin{align}\mathbb E\left[\#\{j< i:|S_i\cap S_j|\geq a\}\right]&=\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\mathbb P(|S_i\cap S_j|\geq a)\\\\&\leq\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{A\in\binom{S_j}a}\left\{A\subset S_i\right\}\right)\\\\&\leq\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\sum_{A\in\binom{S_j}a}\mathbb P(A\subset S_i)\\\\&\leq\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\sum_{A\in\binom{S_j}a}\frac{\binom{d-a}{\ell-a}}{\binom d\ell}\\\\&\leq (i-1)\binom\ell a \frac{\binom{d-a}{\ell-a}}{\binom d\ell}\\\\&<m\binom\ell a \frac{\binom{d-a}{\ell-a}}{\binom d\ell}\\\\&<\frac{\binom da}{\binom \ell a^2}\cdot\binom\ell a \frac{\binom{d-a}{\ell-a}}{\binom d\ell}\\\\&=1\end{align}
therefore, there is a way to choose such $S_i$, inductively, we can build the $S_1,\cdots, S_m$. Notice also that we only needed the slightly weaker assumption of $m\leq\binom da/\binom\ell a^2$ since $i-1<m$

That's a cute one. I like that, if I am not mistaken, one can construct these sets determinsitically (no randomization needed), i.e, say $S_1, ..., S_{i-1}$ are already given, we compute $S_i$ by taking an arbitrary set of size $\ell$ that does not conflict with any of the previous one. This is possible if $\sum_{j = 1}^{i-1} \sum_{A \in \binom{S_j}{a}} \binom{d-a}{\ell-a} < \binom{d}{\ell} $. And this basically is identical to line 4 above. Thanks!
